# Using strace to debug file access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to figure out the full path of a file a running program is trying (and failing) to open.  I'm given to understand that `strace` can do this, but I'm apparently not using it correctly.  The running program is a service, so I don't see an easy way to run it under `strace` directly.  The examples I have seen make it seem like

```
$ sudo strace -p <process id> -e open,access
```

is the correct incantation to attach to the running process, but when I run this I see no output, even though the program in question is logging its failed attempt to open the file.  I don't even see any output with

```
$ sudo strace -p 24249
Process 24249 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0x7f650fe159d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 24250, NULL
```

It's like whatever futex is is being cut off for some reason?  Or is that normal output for the situation?

In any case, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to run strace on the service itself i.e put it on when you start the service manually.

```
strace -ffttTo /tmp/strace.out service <foo> start
```

And pastebin the file generated.

EDIT: Since it is failing to open a file, can you search by the keyword ENOENT or the grep the string `No such file or directory`.

EDIT2: I saw the output again and checked the man page of futex. So, it seems like something accessing the memory location 0x7f650fe159d0 is holding a lock, perhaps a shared lock and not releasing it. The pid  24250 is also an argument. Can you check what this pid is doing.

Also, can you check the kernel function pid 24249 is associated with. It can be shown using wchan option in `ps -eo wchan <pid>` command. I don't remember the full verbose wchan listing but I will get that you for you tomorrow. (it is quite night here).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - for one, the service does not actually start when invoked like that (I get a `[fail]` output message), and two, it creates 43 files named `/tmp/strace.out.*` - I don't know what the significance of the trailing digits in those filenames is or why there are 43 of them.

Comment: Yeah, it is supposed to create them. It is because the -ff traces the processes that the process being strace-ed is forking. Typically if it is failing to open a file you can search by the keyword ENOENT and see whether you get one. And is this a standard service because I can start a service with the syntax specified.     root@soham-Ideapad-Z560:~# strace -ffttTo /tmp/strace.out service rsyslog start
rsyslog start/running, process 2567

Comment: What I mean is that the service "starts" in some fashion but does not keep running, which prevents me from invoking the behavior I'm trying to debug.  It's a Java process so maybe just some failure of the JVM to play nicely when run under strace?